# Proving the composition of a limit function is the limit of the compositions

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find y st $$y=\lim \limits_{t \to 0+} (1+\frac{1}{t})^t $$

As a first step in the proof I read, take the natural log of both sides:
$$\ln(y) = \ln\left(\lim \limits_{t \to 0+} \left(1+ \frac{1}{t}\right)^t\right) $$

The proof stated this is equal to $\lim \limits_{t \to 0+} \ln((1+\frac{1}{t})^t)$

This assumption is intuitive to me but not obvious, ie I haven’t seen this property in discussion of properties of limits. How would I prove this?

Comment: I can't find a x..I guess you meant t→∞..

Comment: @RamanujanXV My bad, fixed

Comment: Oh thanks! This was what I was looking for. I’ll close the question or answer it @Vasya

Comment: @elbecker: You can close it. There are several similar questions on this site, I do not think I need to enter another answer. ProofWiki link: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Composite_Function